# Problem Redirecting From MasterPage in Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a masterpage on which ill check for a condition if condition is true i want to redirect it to a particular view. how can i do this because on masterpage either view() or RedirectToAction() function are available. My condition is

```
if(Session["Name"]==null)
//redirect to login
else
//work as usual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way to redirect from masterpage is

```
 <% if(Session["abcd"]==null) {
 Response.Redirect(Url.Action("actionname","controllername")
 } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you would typically do it in your controller...

alternatively if it is for authentication you can use:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the good old `<% this.Response.Redirect("/controller/action"); %>`
Be aware that redirection logic have to be in your controller, not your view.